# Simple TCP Client in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, tcp

I've been experimenting with TCP clients in C++ and I really wanted to get some feedback on my code since I know it is bad. I would really appreciate some feedback on the class structure I have and the ways I can improve it. I also would love some feedback on any other simple bugs I have (or things in general I can fix).

```
//FOR CODE REVIEW PLEASE GIVE FEEDBACK

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#undef UNICODE
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define port 0001;



std::vector<std::string> split(std::string mystring, std::string delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> subStringList;
    std::string token;
    while (true)
    {
        size_t findfirst = mystring.find_first_of(delimiter);
        if (findfirst == std::string::npos) //find_first_of returns npos if it couldn't find the delimiter anymore
        {
            subStringList.push_back(mystring); //push back the final piece of mystring
            return subStringList;
        }
        token = mystring.substr(0, mystring.find_first_of(delimiter));
        mystring = mystring.substr(mystring.find_first_of(delimiter) + 1);
        subStringList.push_back(token);
    }
    return subStringList;
}

class client {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    //SOCKET cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    char recvBuf[1024];
    PCWSTR ip = L"192.168.86.36";
    public:
        void startWinsock() {
            std::cout << "[+] - Starting our client.\n";
            int rCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
            if (rCode != NO_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "[-] - Error while trying to start winsock.\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        /*
        void prepSocket() {
            SOCKET cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if (cSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                std::cout << "[+] - Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                WSACleanup();
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        */

        void connectClient(SOCKET cSocket) {
            sockaddr_in addrServer;
            addrServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
            InetPton(AF_INET, ip, &addrServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
            addrServer.sin_port = htons(0001);
            memset(&(addrServer.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

            std::cout << "[+] - Connecting to our socket.\n";
            int iResult = connect(cSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addrServer, sizeof(addrServer));
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(cSocket);
                std::cout << "[-] - Connection Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                WSACleanup();
            }
        }

        void sendMessage(SOCKET cSocket,char messageContent[1024]) {

            //char demoMessage[1024] = "[+] - Demo message\n";
            int message = send(cSocket, messageContent, strlen(messageContent), 0);
            if (message == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "[-] - Unable to send demo message: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                closesocket(cSocket);
                WSACleanup();
            }
            std::cout << "[+] - Successfully sent our demo message.\n";

        }

        void recieveMessage(SOCKET cSocket) {
            std::cout << "[+] - Awaiting server response" << std::endl;
            int iResult = recv(cSocket, recvBuf, 1024, 0);
            if (iResult > 0) {
                std::string content;
                for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++) {
                    content += recvBuf[i];
                }
                if (strstr(content.c_str(), "cmd")) {
                    std::string command = split(content, (std::string)"cmd ")[1];
                    std::cout << "COMMAND SHIT NOT IMPLEMENTED\n";
                }
                else if (strstr(content.c_str(), "exit")) {
                    exit(0);
                }
                std::cout << ">  " << content;
            }
            else if (iResult == 0) {
                std::cout << "[-] - Connection closed\n" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "[-] - An error occured: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            }

        }
        void killSocket(SOCKET cSocket) {
            closesocket(cSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }

};

int main() {
    client client;
    client.startWinsock();
    //client.prepSocket();
    SOCKET cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (cSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "[+] - Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    client.connectClient(cSocket);
    client.sendMessage(cSocket,(char *)"works kek :happy_pepe:\n");
    client.recieveMessage(cSocket);
    client.killSocket(cSocket);

}
```

If you would rather have a pastebin link here's one:

Comment: If you want to learn sockets is fine, but I would recommend you to use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html for services, or even better 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.htmlfor more Restfull systems.

Comment: I wrote a (still incomplete) series about sockets for C++: https://lokiastari.com/series/

Comment: You should use a more C++ style portable library instead of windows-only C-style library. Consider `boost::asio` as Networking TS is likely to be modeled after it.

Answer (score 2):

### Code Review

Do you really want to use C functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Sure you can but you may want to use the correct version of this header file for C++ which is `<cstdio>`.

---

Using port 1 is not recommended for normal socket work.

```
#define port 0001;
```

Ports below 1024 are reserved for the OS (and usually specifically allocated to standard services used by the OS).

https://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp

But since you are writing TCP connection `1` is the correct port.

---

To prevent excessive copying pass complex parameters by const reference rather than value (unless you are going to copy them anyway).

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string mystring, std::string delimiter)
```

---

I think we can improve the split a bit:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& mystring, std::string const& delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> subStringList;

    std::string::size_t start = 0;
    std::string::size_t end   = mystring.find_first_of(delimiter);

    while (end != std::string::npos) {
        subStringList.emplace_back(mystring.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + delimiter.size();
    }
    // if the delimiter is the last item in the string
    // then the following will add a blank string to subStringList.
    // If that is not what you want just test to see if start ==  mystring.size()
    subStringList.emplace_back(mystring.substr(start));

    return subStringList;
}
```

---

Remove commented out code from your source.

```
    //SOCKET cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        /*
        void prepSocket() {
            SOCKET cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if (cSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                std::cout << "[+] - Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                WSACleanup();
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        */
```

This is what source control systems are for. Check out github.

---

You only ever want to connect to this specific host?

```
    PCWSTR ip = L"192.168.86.36";
```

I would expect that you want to pass a hostname as a parameter to the client.

---

Is this really part of the `client` class?

```
        void startWinsock() {
            std::cout << "[+] - Starting our client.\n";
            int rCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
            if (rCode != NO_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "[-] - Error while trying to start winsock.\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        }
```

I would make the start up/shotdown of the windowing socket code a separate class `TCPInit` (probably a singelton). Then the constructor of `client` will simply just make sure that the socket stuff has been initialized by getting an instance of `TCPInit`.

---

You don't check the result of this call:

```
            InetPton(AF_INET, ip, &addrServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

---

Did you not define a port macro above?

```
            addrServer.sin_port = htons(0001);
```

---

Don't assume the size of this object is 8.

```
            memset(&(addrServer.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
```

That is what `sizeof` is used for.

---

The value returned by `send()` is not just an error.

```
            int message = send(cSocket, messageContent, strlen(messageContent), 0);
            if (message == SOCKET_ERROR) {
```

You should check the result of `send()` make sure you have sent the whole message. You may need to call `send()` multiple times to send the whole message.

---

This looks like a destructor:

```
        void killSocket(SOCKET cSocket) {
            closesocket(cSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much <3 this is exactly the type of feedback I was looking for.

Comment: I have one question after fully reading your feedback, why do you recommend use sizeof instead of 8 isn't it always going to have an integer value of 8?

Comment: @Backslash Can you show me where it says its 8 in the standard? If so then you can use 8. Otherwise it is an implementation details that will depend on platform. Actually this field `sin_addr` is an ungodly structure `struct in_addr`  that is a combination of several unions depending on platform and age of your OS. You should zero out the whole structure as that is what the API is expecting.

Comment: While searching for where it says that, i was unable to find that so I now realize that I was wrong. Thank you lol

Comment: @Backslash In general using "magic" numbers is bad practice. Even if the value was exactly 8 I would have recomended putting that value into a named constant (e.g. `static int const SizeOfAddr = /*Value*/;`. This has two benefits 1) Named constants give more meaning to your code as they become self documenting. If the value does change in a new version of the OS then you have. only one place in the code to change the value (at the constant).

Answer (score 1):

## Prefer using `getaddrinfo()`

You are using `InetPton()` to convert an IPv4 address to a `sockaddr_in`. However, this function has several drawbacks:

- It does not perform DNS lookups, so you can't use a hostname to connect to a server.
- You have to know up front which address family to use.
- It doesn't fill in all of a sockaddr_in, it only provides you with the address part.

If you use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) you do get DNS lookups, and you don't have to deal with address families explicitly anymore. There is only one drawback with `getaddrinfo()`, and that is that if you provide it with a hostname, you can actually get multiple `struct sockaddr`s back from it. The correct way to deal with this is to loop over all the `sockaddr`s, and try to connect to each one in turn until you get a working connection.

## Don't write number with leading zeroes

In C++, if you write an [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) starting with a zero, it will be treated as an octal number. Lucky for you, the octal number `0001` has the same value as the decimal number `1`. However, if you would have written `0010`, then it would have been the same as `8`.

## Avoid `#define` for defining constants

In C++, it is better to declare constants as `static constexpr` variables. For example:

```
static constexpr std::uint16_t port = 1;
```

This has the advantage that you can give a proper type to the constant, and that the compiler can actually check this declaration for correctness. Your definition was actually incorrect, since you added a semicolon to the macro:

```
#define port 0001;
```

If you would have used this to fill in `sin_port` in `connectClient()` as Martin York suggests in his answer, then the following line:

```
addrServer.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Would have expanded to:

```
addrServer.sin_port = htons(0001;);
```

Which is clearly a syntax error.

## Avoid using C functions on C++ objects

If you use `std::string`, you should prefer to use the member functions of that class to manipulate strings. For example, instead of writing:

```
if (strstr(content.c_str(), "cmd")) {
```

You should write this idiomatic C++ code using [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
if (content.find("cmd") != content.npos) {
```

It's a bit unfortunate that we have to wait for C++23 for [`contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/contains).

Comment: That `getaddrinfo()` looks to be closely modelled on the POSIX function of the same name, so using it is easing the way towards more portability, too.